# File from a hadoop distributed cache is presented as directory

Tags: java, hdfs, hadoop2

When using the DistributedCache in Hadoop, I manage to push the files from hdfs in the driver class like this:

```
FileSystem fileSystem = FileSystem.get(getConf());
DistributedCache.createSymlink(conf);
DistributedCache.addCacheFile(fileSystem.getUri().resolve("/dumps" + "#" + "file.txt"), job.getConfiguration());
```

Then, to read the file, in the setup() of Mapper I do:

```
Path localPaths[] = context.getLocalCacheFiles();
```

The file is located in the cache, under a path /tmp/solr-map-reduce/yarn-local-dirs/usercache/user/appcache/application_1398146231614_0045/container_1398146231614_0045_01_000004/file.txt. But when I read it, I get IOException: file is a directory.

How can one go about solving this?

Comment: did you tried -file option in hadoop jar

Comment: @SreeVeni no. The file is already on hdfs. And actually trying -file on hadoop2, looks it is not supported. Or perhaps I'm missing something?